# Error with php function in "mysqli select" prepare statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I create a function to call some data from database with left-join and prepare statement.

Here is the sketch of the php function:

```
function getStock()
{
    global $mysqli;
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare 
            ("SELECT     products.`product_name`, product_category.`price`
              FROM products    
                LEFT JOIN  product_category
                ON         products.product_category_id = product_category.id

                WHERE      products.id = ?");

    $id=3; 
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->fetch();
    return $stmt;
```

In the view page I do this:

```
    $resultsTicket = getStock();
    $results = $resultsTicket->num_rows;
    var_dump($results);
    if ($resultsTicket->num_rows > 0) {
        while($resultsTicket->fetch()){
```

However in the var_dump I only get int(0)

I don't know anymore how to find the error there beside the var_dump. Please help me in the above code. Thank you!

**[UPDATE]**

```
$query = "SELECT     products.`product_name`, product_category.`price`
          FROM       products    
          LEFT JOIN  product_category
          ON         products.product_category_id = product_category.id
          WHERE      products.id = 3;

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {     
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($product_name, $price);
    //$stmt->fetch();
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $product_name, $price);
    }   
        $stmt->close();}
    return $stmt;

}
```

In the code above I get one data/row from database.

Comment: $stmt->bind_param("s", $id); should be $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);

Comment: ^ that - or `$id="3";` - You're presently using an int and trying to bind a string.

Comment: i have changed that to `"i"` and `"3"`, however the result still int(0) 

`object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(1) ["field_count"]=> int(11) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) }`

Comment: *"i have changed that to "i" and "3","* - it's "or" and not "and". Do one **or** the other; not both. Plus, make sure the column is an `int` if you're going to use int and *vice-versa*.

Comment: I still don't know what is wrong :/

Comment: It's probably something to do with your `WHERE` clause then. You have `WHERE products.id = ?` so you're probably choosing the wrong table/id. Where you have `product_category.id`

Comment: the problem is your are returning the statement object, fetch all the values, and return it. thats about it.

Comment: Replace `$stmt->execute();` with `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$mysqli->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` see if anything comes of it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have replaced it but there is no additional error message showing up. Only the int(0) stay there. What does it mean? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know Alisa. Maybe @Ghost might have an idea. JOINS aren't my strong points in SQL.

Comment: @alisa first thing to diagnose is, make sure that the query really yields at least one row/result using `id = 3` not hard to test, put it in your phpMyadmin and test `id = 3`. if its good, then just prepare, fetch, return. here's an example, straight from the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php. anyways the `$stmt` object says it all `["num_rows"]=> int(0) `

Comment: @Ghost, thank you for the reference. Please see my update, where I get one record from database.

Comment: @alisa you're already close, instead of printf just use a container which will hold all the values that are being fetched (preferably an array) then just return it

Comment: @Ghost I am sorry I didn't see your last comment. Yeah, that's it. Btw, Thank you, Ghost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got enough help with the guys, If you still not sure how to code it, here you go:

**Single record**

```
$query = "SELECT     products.`product_name`, product_category.`price`
          FROM       products    
          LEFT JOIN  product_category
          ON         products.product_category_id = product_category.id
          WHERE      products.id = 3";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {     
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($product_name, $price);
    $row = array();
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $row = array('product_name'=>$product_name, 'price'=>$price);
    }   
    $stmt->close();
}
return $row;
```

**Multiple Record:**

```
$query = "SELECT     products.`product_name`, product_category.`price`
          FROM       products    
          LEFT JOIN  product_category
          ON         products.product_category_id = product_category.id
          WHERE      products.id = 3";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {     
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($product_name, $price);
    $rows = array();
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $rows[] = array('product_name'=>$product_name, 'price'=>$price);
    }   
    $stmt->close();
}
return $rows;
```

---

**Example in PDO:**

```
$query = "SELECT     products.`product_name`, product_category.`price`
          FROM       products    
          LEFT JOIN  product_category
          ON         products.product_category_id = product_category.id
          WHERE      products.id = 3";

if ($stmt = $pdo->prepare($query)) {     
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
}
return $rows;
```

Comment: Yeah, these guys are so kind to help like Ghost, Fred-ii, etc etc. Thanks to all of you! <3

Comment: One silly question: how to echo each column name in the view page I have? Should I echo it like: `echo $product_name`, `echo $price` or? I am so sorry for this kind of question (newbie) :p.

Comment: @alisa yes they are great guys, I really admire their hard work. Yes you can use `echo` or `printf` just like you did in your code

Comment: Man, is there a simple way for this without I have to mention all selected column in `$stmt->bind_result(...)` because I can't imagine if I have to select a bunch of column from many join tables. Btw, Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: @alisa you can try [mysqli_result::fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)  you will need `mysqlnd`. But I recommend you to use `PDO` because mysqli sucks no need to suffer from it

Comment: Well, if you say so, I will use PDO next time. Thank you, Meda. Have a nice day! :)

Comment: @alisa you can start from now if you want, See my edit and notice how much simpler it is

Comment: Hi Meda, thank you very much for the update answer. Wow, I get many things on php from you. :) Happy New Year!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are executing and fetching within the function but returning the statement. There are two possible changes you can make.

1. Execute and fetch within the function, then loop through the results and return an array representing the results.
2. Return the statement from the function and perform the execute and fetch where you are using the result of the function.

Comment: I don't know but I think you are right. I will try to make up the code to find out what the main problem is and how to use it as how I expected. Anyway, thanks! :)